# requirejs - not loading certainly with proper path given

Tags: javascript, requirejs, pug

I am using 'requirejs' for my app development, it was worked properly but certainly it is not working now. all the path are correct. but i am getting error on load the page

error i am getting:

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:3000
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/js/lib/require.js //but exactly the file is here.
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

here is my html for jade:

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
    head
        title= name
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='styles/bootstrap.min.css')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='styles/stylesheet/style.css')

    body

        <h1>I am basic testing</h1> 
        script(data-main="js/main", src="js/lib/require.js")
```

here is my main.js

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl:'js/',
    paths:{
        "jQuery":'lib/jquery',
        "underscore":"lib/underscore",
        "backbone":"lib/backbone",
        "marionette":"lib/Marionette"
    },
    "shim":{
        "jQuery":{
            exports:"$"
        },
        "underscore":{
            exports:"_"
        },
        "backbone":{
            exports:"Backbone",
            deps:["underscore"]
        },
        "marionette":{
            exports:"Marionette",
            deps:["backbone"]
        }
    }
});

requirejs(['app'], function(app){});
```

Any one help me to fix this issue?

screen shot from browser:

[image: browser erro]

Comment: yes. the file is there

Comment: Why the type is text/plain? Something is wrong with your server

Comment: What kind of server is behind that and how is it configured?

Comment: @chchrist you are correct. I am using nodejs, it is not properly parse my js file because of wrong module integration. issue fixed. thanks

Comment: @3gwebtrain If your issue is fixed then you should do one of the following: a. Post an answer and edit your question so that the link between the answer and the question is clear, or b. Delete your question. If you think the issue and solution would be of use to others then do "a". If not, then do "b". (I can't emphasize this too much: if you decide to answer your question, **you must edit your question** to show a clear link between question and answer.)