# 404 not found for foundation source files

Tags: laravel, nginx, path, zurb-foundation

Running on nginx+laravel+foundation(simple css copy put into folders inside public directory) with a simple route and view and get 404 error for every source foundation file.
it looks like this for every file:

Remote Address:127.0.0.1:3000
Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:3000/css/normalize.css
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found

tried different path notations(full, relative, via assets method or without it): same result.
can't find something informative on the issue within nginx logs.

and  Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not definedregister:65 (anonymous function) for these lines:

```
  <script src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).foundation();
  </script>
```

should be something simple, but just can't get it myself.

Comment: actually, I'm getting the same error with twitter bootstrap source file. seems like nginx settings error, probably.

Comment: Привет :) Why don't you look into your nginx's error log file?

Comment: привет! why didn't look? I did it as mentioned above. but access.log states the same info I can get from chrome devtools: 404 error while trying to get the source. error.log contains no errors at all. some stupid stuff, I know, but what to do? I've run out of ideas.

Comment: found some ideas here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23624190/requirejs-not-loading-certainly-with-proper-path-given. and this is my errors from devtools:
normalize.css GET 404 text/html register:15 0 B 1.22 s 
foundation.css GET 404 text/html register:16 0 B 2.39 s 
app.css GET 404 text/html register:19 0 B 3.59 s 
modernizr.js GET 404 text/html register:21 0 B 4.78 s 
jquery.js GET 404 text/html register:62 0 B 5.98 s 
foundation.min.js GET 404 text/html register:63 0 B 7.16 s  as I see, there should be text/css type of file and there is something wrong with file parsing by nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just fixed it: the problem was with my rewrites.
deleted this line from nginx.conf in the main server block:

```html
rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
```

and got all the source files with no errors.